# "depending on something" ... singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number, definite-articles

I'm writing a paper in which the experimental results with two different antibodies are compared across different brain regions.

I want to write something like:

> We used antibodies A and B for this experiment. We obtained distinct results depending on the antibody and brain region.

Here each experiment only uses either one of the two antibodies.

I wonder if "depending on" should be followed by "the antibodies and brain regions" (the + plural) or "the antibody and brain region" (the + singular).

Actually, I have no problem with "depending on antibody and brain region", i.e. uncountable and abstract use of nouns without an article. This kind of example phrase can be found in dictionaries.

However, as soon as there comes a "the", I cannot really tell what is right.

If I consider the following sentence,

> We obtained distinct results depending on the antibody and brain region examined.

then "the + singular" sounds natural to me, for only one antibody or region can be examined at one time.

Could someone please give me some advice on this?

Comment: I assume 'labelling' has its usual sense here, ie you label your results. _This experiment resulted in our devising distinct labelling patterns determined by both the antibody involved and the brain region examined._ But I'd prefer a complete rewrite. I feel you're trying too hard to avoid starting with 'we'.

Comment: Cheers. In order not to go into technical details which is not relevant, the original sentence has been radially simplified. I'll try to clarify the context.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly for the sake of parallel phrase structure
but also for terminological accuracy,
adding **tested** and **the** would produce a gem
acceptable to any medical journal:

> We obtained distinct results depending on the antibody **tested**
>   and **the** brain region examined.

Plural agreement among nouns would, as noted in the question,
decrease the scientific precision of the sentence:

> We obtained distinct results depending on the antibodies tested
>   and the brain regions examined.

The following variation is a partial concession to the grammar of plurals
that also avoids the slightly ambiguous use of *depending*:

> We obtained distinct results for different combinations of
>   antibody and brain region.

Comment: Thank you for the great reply. This is very helpful and well explains what I felt.